# Dynamic memory allocation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have two questions:

1. What is the **MATLAB** equivalent of **C**'s [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)?
   Is that [`reshape()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)?
2. How can I initialize a **MALTAB** vector that can be used to incrementally add new elements of object/struct type?

For instance, `my_vector = zeros(1, N)` cannot be used in case of objects/structs, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB memory allocation is done automatically. I.e., adding elements to a vector automatically performs a `realloc`

```
x = [ 1 2 3 ];
x(4) = 4;  % performs realloc
% now x == [1 2 3 4]

x(2) = []; % deletes element 2
% now x == [1 3 4]
```

To create an array of objects I used `repmat` in the past. Since an object in the general case needs to be constructed from some data, I found the replication is often the best if nothing else is known about a class. To create an 2x3x4 array of default constructed objects of class `CLS`, use

```
x = repmat( CLS(), [ 2 3 4] )
```

I found this more appropriate than writing

```
x = CLS();
x(2,3,4) = CLS();
```

which probably also would work but is awkward to read and probably could have subtle bugs if the class is not implemented correctly.

`struct`s can be created also with repmat, or, alternatively, by providing cell arrays to the `struct` constructor function, e.g.,

```
x = struct( 'a', { 1 2 3}, 'b', { 5 6 7} );
% now x is a 1x3 struct array
```